# What is the meaning of this format `%02hhx`?

Tags: c, hex, format-specifiers

I saw in some functions that in order to convert number to hexadecimal format, using this format: `printf("%02hhx", some_char);` , but I don't understand why, and what is the meaning of this format ?

Comment: Try `char c = 0x89; printf("%hhx\n", c);` and compare `printf("%x\n", c);`.

Comment: Due to the *default argument promotions*, when you pass a `char` or `short int` to `printf`, it actually receives an `int`.  The `hh` modifier lets you explicitly tell `printf` that what you actually passed was a `char`, so that `printf` can "trim the result back down", if it matters.

Comment: @user123454321: `printf("%02hhx", some_char);` will never print “303031” in an ordinary C implementation. If you got that output, it was because some other code was used, such as a loop with this `printf` in it. Likely you printed the characters of the string “001” using `printf("%02hhx", some_char);` for each of them. The ASCII codes for the characters “0” and “1” are 48 and 49, which are 30 and 31 in hexadecimal.

Comment: I said, "compare `printf("%x\n", c);`", but there's a catch.  The results you get will depend on an implementation detail of your machine and compiler.  If type `char` is signed by default on your system, you will see a different and surprising result with `printf("%x\n", c);`, and this explains why you need `%hhx`.  But if type `char` is unsigned by default, you will see the same results for both, and it may therefore seem like you didn't need the `hh`.  But the code is definitely better with the `hh`.

Answer (score 2):

Format string `"%02hhx"` means:

- `0`: Results that would require less than specified field width shall be printed with leading `0`s.
- `2`: use at least 2 characters to format the value
- `x` Print in hexadecimal format.
- `hh` The provided parameter for `x` is only a `char`, not an `int` For values `0..127` it doesn't matter if you add the `hh` but values above could get sign extended and would be printed with lots of leading `F`.

The result will just be a hexadecimal value with 2 digits.

Comment: but for example for `"001"` i get the following string: `"303031"` , and it's not the hexadecimal format of `"001"` ... where does this "3" come from?

Comment: @user123454321 That's a different question.  `"001"` is a string with three characters, `'0'`, `'0'`, and `'1'`.  `"ABC"` would get you `414243`.

Comment: @SteveSummit oh i understand. do you know how can i put string that of hexadecimal-digits as hexadecimal format in file ?

Comment: @user123454321 If the string already contains hexadeximal digits, just use `%s`.

Comment: @user123454321 Character `'0'` is printed as hexadecimal number `"30"`, `'1'´ is ´"31"`. If you print those 3 characters, you get `"30301"`