# String.data(using: .utf8): What is the effect of having the argument specified?

Tags: json, swift, parsing

From an video-tutorial, which I'm currently using for learning:

```
let data = """
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "firstname": "John",
            /* ... */
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)
```

What does the .data-method?
From what I read in the documentation, I would say it loads the data into a buffer.

But what's the argument with the label 'using'?

**Can someone explain in a easy way what happens there?**

Comment: Do you understand what an encoding is?

Comment: @Sweeper Well, yes. But I don't understand what the specification does in the shown case. Is it put into RAM as data with UTF8-encoding?

Comment: You make it sound like the string wasn't in RAM... Anyway, `Data` represents a sequence of bytes. `String` represents text. Encodings are ways to turn text into bytes. You are saying that the string should be turned into bytes using the specific encoding called "UTF-8". All clear?

Comment: Are you looking for the correct doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/data(using:allowlossyconversion:) ? Here `.utf8` is short for `String.Encoding.utf8`. So convert the String into data using the UTF8 encoding. You can put other values and compare if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes. Thanks a big bunch.

Comment: @Larme Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sweeper If you like turn to your comment into an answer. I'm goanna accept it.

Comment: A test `print("ê".data(using: .utf8)?.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()); print("ê".data(using: .utf32)?.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())` The `.map{...}...` is just to convert data (high level class for "bytes") into hex string. With gives outputs: "c3aa" & "fffe0000ea000000", different encoding, so different conversion logic so different values.

Comment: @Larme what purpose does the "hh" serve in your format string? It seems to give the same results using "%2x" without the "hh" (And I prefer upper case X to give upper chase hexadecimal, but that's personal preference.)

Comment: @DuncanC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74797942/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-format-02hhx & https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html ? I just copied it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift I use both, I don't mind personnaly for the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is converting a `String` to [`Data`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data), because presumably this will then get passed to a `JSONDecoder` to decode. `Data` represents

> A byte buffer in memory

so a sequence of bytes. Note that `String` does not represent a sequence of bytes. It is a sequence of `Character`s. To convert `Character`s to bytes, you need an [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Different encodings can convert the same character to different byte sequences.

`.utf8` is one of the encodings. There are [many more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding). [JSON data should be transmitted in UTF-8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1), so that's why `.utf8` is used here.

Comment: I would also mention that when encoding utf8 this method will never fail and that it is safe to force unwrap it when using that encoding type. A better option would be using Data non fallible initializer and pass the string utf8 property value to it.